# Shielding effect of d electrons

Tags: atomic-radius

In transition elements shielding effect is observed . Due to this zinc shows abnormality in atomic size.
But at the same time we also say that gallium has same similar size as  aluminium due to poor shielding effect of **d** electrons . Why is it that d electrons have good shielding effect in case of zinc but poor shielding effect in case of gallium?

Comment: Slater's rule may be used for quantitative reasoning

Answer (score 1):

When we are talking about zinc... We have to think about period trends. So in periods along moving from left to right covalent radius decreases. But in case of transition metal..

Two effects works first is $Z_{eff}$. Another effect is electronic repulsion.At the starting the no of electron in $d-$ orbital are less so $Z_{eff}$ is dominant over electronic repulsion but as we are moving alosng d-orbital electronic effect become dominant factor over $Z_{eff}$, So in the middle redius become almost constant and at the end it increases.

When we are talking about gallium and Aluminium radius comparision thats mean we are talking about group trends ,So in group trend abnormal size is due to poor shielding effect and relativistic effect. Normal trend on going down the size increases from aluminium to gallium size decreases because here a poor shielding of 3-d orbital present so $Z_{eff}$ penetarate and valence shell contract so size decreases.

Comment: Why shouldn't electronic repulsions taken into account in case of gallium and aluminium size comparison?

Comment: We can compare electronic repulsion in case of zinc and gallium because as both have d10 orbital.  And it more clear when we see radius of gallium  is 187pm and radius of zinc is 139 pm.  But when we are talking  about Aluminum  there is no d orbital and galium has.  So that's can be a possible  explaination because  we don't  have d orbital  in case of aluminum  and have d orbital in case of galium so basically  we can't  compare it.  I can just mention Galium radius 187 pm and zinc radius 139 pm and Aluminum  radius 184 pm. So we can see difference  of radius length of zinc and gallium is to

Comment: Yes the values are correct they are as expected . But we know that **there are electronic repulsions in gallium and  they aren't in aluminium** . So I am asking that why can't gallium atom be bigger than aluminium because of the **above reason** .

Comment: I mean gallium should be far more bigger.

Comment: In atomic size [neutral atom] Ga fits perfectly in, to the right of Zn and below Al. When comparing ions Ga loses the s and p electrons so the outer electrons remaining are the 3d10 These do not shield each other so Ga+3 is rather small.